# How to import a service from application A into application B?

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy

So I have 2 applications : A and B  . application A contains a service that I created and I want to use in my application B.
Is there a way to use that service instead of writing the code again?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you trying to import something from one file to another, or do this all in a single file?

Comment: Do you mean how to use or consume the api's that provide the service in application A inside application B? Not sure about your question. Can you be clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @taurus   I need to import the service from app A as an autowired dependency into my app B so I can directly use (sorta like a bean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to use that service instead of writing the code again?

Yes.  The typical thing to do is to put the shared code in a library and consume that library from the applications which want to share that code.

btw... If you are usning Gradle, the `micronaut-library` plugin at https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.micronaut.library will be helpful.